# Create dynamic library that implements multiple LLVM passes

Tags: cmake

I have a static library, which consists of several passes and is a part of `opt`. I want to make it dynamic and create one dylib file, so I could call `opt`, loading created `.dylib` and passing the desired LLVM pass. I'm using LLVM 7.0.

I created such dylib file with the help of Xcode (by adding to already existing dynamic library target additional passes), but I can't find any information, how to make it with the help of CMake.

At the moment, CMake file of the library looks like this:

```
add_llvm_library(MyLibrary
Pass1.cpp
Pass2.cpp
Pass3.cpp
...
PassN.cpp
DEPENDS
intrinsics_gen
)
```

What is expected is performing such command:

```
path/to/opt -load /path/to/MyLibrary.dylib -Pass3 ...
```

It isn't clear to me, whether it is possible to leave the structure of the library as is or if I have to modify it, by giving each pass a `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: You should try passing the following option when invoking CMake `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=On`. More info [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this, faced up to the problem of multiple dependencies, which required to include several libraries. Linked libraries required required another libraries being linked. After a while, took a Hello `CMakeLists.txt`, which was provided in LLVM, as an example. Instead of `add_llvm_library`, wrote `add_llvm_loadablemodule`, making such `CMakeLists.txt`

```
if (WIN32 OR CYGWIN)
    set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS ...)
endif()

add_llvm_loadable_module(Mylib_Dylib
    Pass1.cpp
    Pass2.cpp
    ...
    PassN.cpp
    PLUGIN_TOOL
    opt
)
```

It build Mylib.dylib, and it was possible to call a pass from it.

Answer (score 1):

Since [LLVM 8.0](https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#non-comprehensive-list-of-changes-in-this-release) the `add_llvm_loadable_module` CMake directive has been removed from LLVM. It has been replaced with using `add_llvm_library` with the `MODULE` argument.

```
if (WIN32 OR CYGWIN)
    set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS ...)
endif()

add_llvm_library(Mylib_Dylib MODULE
    Pass1.cpp
    Pass2.cpp
    ...
    PassN.cpp
    PLUGIN_TOOL
    opt
)
```